# Different behaviors of embedded images between Gmail and Outlook

Tags: html, image, email, html-email, embedded-resource

I'm trying to send an email with an embedded image using generated HTML in the backend,

and I see that every email client is behaving differently.

Outlook only supports base64 format, and Gmail doesn't.

Gmail supports a regular image src, and also a background image, while Outlook doesn't.

I'm wondering if there is a generic solution for this issue

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Different email clients support different things at different levels. You can have a look at caniemail.com for support details across popular email clients. For example:

- [background-image](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-background-image/)
- [base64 image format](https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-base64/)

A regular `<img src>` pointing to an hosted image usually works well, though.

Comment: it doesn't work well on Outlook :(

Comment: The only way  to fake background images in the Outlooks on Windows is by using VML. Have a look at a tool like [Backgrounds.cm](https://backgrounds.cm/).