# How to fix HTML-Email Images Breaking in different email clients

Tags: html, css, html-email, power-automate

Hi I'm using power automate to send email with images, But it breaks on google but in outlook it works perfectly fine.

> This is the result on Outlook:

[image]

> This is the result on Gmail:

[image]

I've already use Base64 Encoding and I don't know what to do next.

Comment: "I've already use Base64 Encoding" - what exactly do you even mean by this? (`data:` URIs? Uuencode? Base64-encoding the entire message body? attachments? what?)

Comment: Bear in mind that the user/their email client can choose to block all images, never mind whether they are prepared to show base64 encoded ones, so be prepared for people to not see them.

Comment: @Dai I've used this format on my HTML image part

<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4RiDRXhpZgAATU0AKgA..." width="100" height="50" alt="base64 test">

And I didn't encode the entire message body.

Comment: @A Haworth I'm using sharepoint as my storage for my Images, Is it  has something to do with my sharepoint site my site is private and I'm not sure if there is blocking part on my site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different behaviors of embedded images between Gmail and Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69389869/different-behaviors-of-embedded-images-between-gmail-and-outlook)

Answer (score 0):

You have given us the answer: you used base64 encoding when there is not good support for that across email providers. See https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-base64/

Upload the images to a website or other public repository (a CDN or storage place publicly accessible), and then use `<img src="https://www.place.com/imagehere23423423.jpg" ...>`

Comment: "Upload the images to a website or other public repository (a CDN or storage place publicly accessible), and then use" **no no no no no** do not do this! Almost all modern (and all privacy-protecting) mail clients block all externally loaded resources for obvious reasons - Instead use MIME embedded images (the kind that use the `cid:` URI scheme) which has full support in all e-mail clients written in the past 25 years.

Comment: @Dai no no no no no. You're talking about a horrible process where an image is attached to an email and referenced in the HTML. That could have spam filter impacts from that method for all you know. Industry standard is the method Nathan has mentioned.

Comment: Hi @Natan I'm using sharepoint as my storage for my images, And I tried Base64 and Non Base64 still not working on other email client, For the CDN/Public Repository my company doesn't allow us to use public website/repository for security purposes.

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein There are plenty of articles like this on the web ( https://www.enovapoint.com/how-to-make-images-in-emails-load-automatically/ ) - if always using external images really was the "industry standard" then articles like this wouldn't need to exist. Additionally, what on earth do MIME `cid:`-style attachments (**not** "file attachments" that users see directly) have to do with spam filters? Spam filtering based on `cid:` attachments makes no sense :S

Comment: @Dai Funny, that article specifically talks about internal emailing for organisations, not full blown marketing emails. There is a big difference. Just because there is an industry standard, doesn't mean there aren't other methods of build, right or wrong. As a software engineer, you should be well aware of that fact.

Comment: The cid method is circumventing security protocols setup by organisations or the users themselves, plain and simple. Also, these images are now attached to the email. Attachments on emails sent by platforms can flag spam filters. Do you know for certain attached images references via a cid aren't flagged by filters?

Comment: @CarloAngeles Ok so your images are working internally (Outlook) because the images are accessible internally via SharePoint, but not externally since SharePoint is an intranet, and not public. At my work, there are methods to upload external data - you need to seek out someone or a team that can upload the images for you safely. There will be a way.